# Changing a value in first object results in second object change

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an object array:

```
const test = new Array(2).fill({ a: 1, b: 2 });

test[0].a = 3;
```

I just want to reassign "a" in the first object, but when I use the above code, both "a" gets reassigned. And the output:

```
[ { a: 3, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 2 } ]
```

Comment: If it's the same reference, then it will also be changed. This is the general rule for objects, excluding primitive values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in eg [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) of the Array fill method

> If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.

A possible solution:

```js
const test = Array.from({ length: 2 }).map(() => ({ a: 1, b: 2 }));

test[0].a = 3;

console.log(test);
```